# Multiple desktop panels (xservers?) opening with each reboot

Tags: linux, drivers, linux-mint, nvidia-graphics-card

I recently installed a dual boot of Linux Mint and Windows 7.

One of the first things I did was install nVidia drivers via "additional drivers". I then proceeded to configure settings, and saved to the X config - this solved the issue of my multiple monitors not being detected.

However, this also introduced an issue of opening multiple desktop panels (X servers?) with each reboot - in fact, it seems another one is added with each additional reboot:

[image: Screenshot]

I was wondering if anybody has had this experience before, or has any suggestions of how to correct this.

Comment: Could you post some more information please? Try these commands: `ps aux | grep X` and `ps aux grep panel`. Also maybe your xorg.conf file. Which desktop manager are you using? Cinnamon, Gnome3, Mate?

Comment: I'm on cinnamon. It seems that after changes are made in nvidia-settings, the save to xorg.conf is what causes this. Upon reboot, it seems to reboot into gnome as shown above.

Comment: Try asking this over at mint's [cinnamon forum](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewforum.php?f=208), the cinnamon devs hang out there and should be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Right, I'm going to have a go because I'm intrigued. First of all, are you *sure* you are using cinnamon? That looks more like MATE.

In any case, I have no idea what is going on but I might be able to point you in the right direction. First of all, you are *not* running muliple X servers. What you have is a Desktop Environment (Window Manager) problem. Here are a few things you can try:

1. Follow [this](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/955) guide to install the latest cinnamon version. It has quite a few improvements. You might also post a comment there since Clem, the linux mint and cinnamon lead developer, seems to often respond to comments there.
2. The command `ps` list currently running programs. Look at the output of `ps aux | grep panel`. In cinnamon you should get nothing, in MATE you should get something like:

   ```
   $ ps aux | grep panel
   terdon 3623 12.3  3.2 1008896 266816 ?      Sl   03:31   1:19 /usr/bin/mate-s
   ```

   If you get *many* such lines, at least we know that it is this program that is launched multiple times.
3. Have a look at what programs are set to launch automatically. Try looking for "Startup Applications" in the menu, or run `gnome-session-properites` from a terminal. Also look at the contents of your `~/.config/autostart/` directory.
4. Rename your config directory and log in again:

   ```
   $ mv ~/.config ~/.config.old
   ```

   This will remove most of your personal settings, effectively resetting your session preferences. The next time you log in, a default ~/.config directory will be created for you. If the problem goes away, you know it was with one of the settings there. You can now copy the individual subdirectories from ~/.config.old to the new ~/.config. If you log out and back in every few copies, you should be able to identify the culprit.
5. Make a new user and log with that username. If the problem is gone, then most probably some other settings file (those that begin with a dot '.') in your home directory was at fault.
6. If that *is* Cinnamon, check the error tab in the cinnamon looking glass (accessible through the troubleshooting sub-menu in the panel properties menu).
7. You might also find useful information in `~/.xsession-errors` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.
8. Come to the linux mint forums. There are subforums for each of the DEs shipped with Mint. Cinnamon is [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewforum.php?f=208) and MATE [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewforum.php?f=206). That's where the people most likely to be able to help you hang out. If you do, please send me a private message (I use the same username and avatar on that site) so I can find your question easily.

OK, that should keep you busy for a while :). I expect option 4 will fix your problem but I'd rather find a more elegant solution than that kind of brute approach.

Comment: Checking "enable xinemera" within nvidia-settings corrected some issues. However, out of frustration, I then installed Ubuntu instead and it works like a charm. I believe this probably due an older graphics card - Quadro FX 1400